# What does "明微推远，憭若蓍蔡" mean?

Tags: classical-chinese

I got an answer from the internet but cannot make too much out of it.

My biggest issue is 蓍蔡. A search reveals this to mean "a person of high moral standing" or some sort of big turtle. So I am not quite sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation:

> 明微推遠，憭若蓍蔡
>
> [his words are] clear (明), precise (微), incredibly profound (推遠), as wise (憭) as that of (若) the most renowned and famous (蓍蔡)

As for the reference definition for「蓍蔡」:

> **漢語大詞典**
>
> 2. 比喻德高望重的人。
>
>    - 明　張居正　《少師存齋徐相公七十壽序》：＂天下方以公為蓍蔡，何可一日無也。＂
>    - 明　陸深　《溪山餘話》：＂公和易，不事邊幅，喜為後生輩談論講說，終日不倦……所謂國家之蓍蔡，若人是已。＂
>    - 清　褚人穫　《堅瓠秘集・守龜》：＂古人目老成人，則曰國之蓍蔡。＂

Comment: 蓍蔡 - how do you derive the definition "most renowned and famous"?

Comment: @AndrewWang see edits. The "fame" meaning has an intellectual, wisdom, or morality component to it - it's not the kind of fame of movie stars.

Comment: This comment is a bit late and I'm not sure whether I should ask this in a new question; how should I interpret "古人目老成人，則曰國之蓍蔡"? 

I think 目 refers to 看待, and I am not sure of what role 則 and 曰 play.

Answer (score 1):

the 國語辭典 has the entry ["蓍蔡"](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000127368), which stated:

> 比喻有先見之明的人

roughly, as a metaphor of "person with foresight"

> 上稽天時．下測物變．明微推遠．憭若蓍蔡

understand the tinniest (明微), able to predict long time ahead (推遠); smart (憭．慧也) as (若) any persons with foresight (蓍蔡)

http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QjAxMTg4